# Jquery toggle class expend and collapse automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was trying to make drop-down navigation. I used this code in CSS and try to toggle active class to make ul drop-down.

```
header nav ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #333;
    display: none;
}

header nav ul li.active ul{
    display: block;
}
```

I used this J-query code, To toggle class.

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

But problem is when i clicked li to drop-down menu it expend and then collapse automatic in one click. I want to expend for one click and then collapse that when i click again. But it expend and collapse automatically for one click. Please help me, i am new in coding.

Comment: Add your html as well please

Comment: see the example of toggleClass https://codepen.io/atwright147/pen/HEfDu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you'll have to adjust your Html code.

Code Snippet for your easy reference.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li.active ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu-item {
  max-width: 130px;
}

ul.menu-item li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <ul class="menu-item">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Abous Us
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem1</li>
        <li>Lorem2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>What We Do
      <ul>
        <li>Web Development</li>
        <li>IoT</li>
        <li>AI</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now i got it. I didn't put any link or # symbol in

link tag.

Then i put # tag in link like < a href="#">

and it solve the problem. I didn't know it can be a problem.  Thank you Faizul Hassan brother,  I could understand my problem by experiment with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Now i got it. I didn't put any link or # symbol in

link tag.

Then i put # tag in link  like
< a href="#">

and it solve the problem.
I didn't know it can be a problem.